# ERROR: No jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation named node found

Tags: node.js, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to setup jenkins on a windows machine. The job is configured using multi-branch pipeline. The job script is failing when trying to run npm install with below error.

ERROR: No jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation named node found

I've already installed nodejs plugin for jenkins and configured jenkins to point to correct nodejs executable folder in Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration -> NodeJS.
When running npm install from command prompt, it works fine.
Has anyone faced this issue before? Any clues/direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This one could be off the wall, and personally haven't seen it documented anywhere, but when setting up the global tool in config is super important.

For example:

[image]

The name of that particular install is node, if I try to call it with

```
tool 'npm'
```

It's not going to work. This is a shot in the dark, but it caught me once before.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working solution
[image]

```
tools {
    nodejs "NodeJs"
}
```